# xamarin.forms ios app starts crashing randomly

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, crash, google-ads-api

after last update our app start crashing randomly on some user devices . i can't get this crash on my ipad in release version, so may be it is device specific or ios version specific.
crash seems to be google ads related.

while i am trying to find a reason , may be somebody has an idea where to dig

thanks in advance. below info from appcentre.ms . it's from app main crash ,but crash happens in different places

pplication.Main (System.String[] args)
SIGABRT: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Can't add self as subview Native stack trace: 0 CoreFoundation 0x000000019ad74604 409609CD-8410-38E1-BA5D-BDED609D2018 + 1222148 1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000019aa96bcc objc_exception_throw + 56 2 CoreFoundation 0x000000019ac6ab28 409609CD-8410-38E1-BA5D-BDED609D2018 + 133928 3 UIKitCore 0x000000019f2c6c54 3062FF32-2182-37A2-A5F9-B38F6FB6B8C3 + 15547476 4 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001035e1108 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 18464880 5 MyApp.iOS 0x000000010355ba94 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 17918460 6 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000103781720 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20170376 7 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001037654d8 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20055104 8 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000103764a20 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20052360 9 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000103760c60 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20036552 10 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000103760354 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20034236 11 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000103763d24 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20049036 12 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000103763a30 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20048280 13 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000103765938 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20056224 14 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001037654d8 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20055104 15 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000103764a20 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20052360 16 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000103760c60 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20036552 17 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000103760354 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20034236 18 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000103763d24 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20049036 19 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000103763a30 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20048280 20 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000103765938 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20056224 21 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001037654d8 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20055104 22 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000103764a20 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20052360 23 MyApp.iOS 0x000000010376f548 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20096176 24 MyApp.iOS 0x000000010376e4b0 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20091928 25 MyApp.iOS 0x000000010376e328 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20091536 26 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001050f8e8c GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 46874100 27 MyApp.iOS 0x000000010376a5cc GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20075828 28 MyApp.iOS 0x000000010378f6f4 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 20227676 29 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001028acc20 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 4619144 30 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001055382a8 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 51327504 31 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001055f3784 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 52094700 32 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001055f6fe8 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 52109136 33 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001024e523c GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 655780 34 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001024fb474 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 746460 35 UIKitCore 0x000000019f0138b0 3062FF32-2182-37A2-A5F9-B38F6FB6B8C3 + 12716208 36 UIKitCore 0x000000019efe1640 3062FF32-2182-37A2-A5F9-B38F6FB6B8C3 + 12510784 37 UIKitCore 0x000000019effe364 3062FF32-2182-37A2-A5F9-B38F6FB6B8C3 + 12628836 38 UIKitCore 0x000000019f2cdc7c 3062FF32-2182-37A2-A5F9-B38F6FB6B8C3 + 15576188 39 QuartzCore 0x00000001a18674ac BA9ECCEE-9F61-3BAA-B8A8-8EB3B7E0A24F + 1381548 40 QuartzCore 0x00000001a186d604 BA9ECCEE-9F61-3BAA-B8A8-8EB3B7E0A24F + 1406468 41 QuartzCore 0x00000001a1878148 BA9ECCEE-9F61-3BAA-B8A8-8EB3B7E0A24F + 1450312 42 QuartzCore 0x00000001a17c0e34 BA9ECCEE-9F61-3BAA-B8A8-8EB3B7E0A24F + 699956 43 QuartzCore 0x00000001a17ea7c4 BA9ECCEE-9F61-3BAA-B8A8-8EB3B7E0A24F + 870340 44 QuartzCore 0x00000001a17eb1d8 BA9ECCEE-9F61-3BAA-B8A8-8EB3B7E0A24F + 872920 45 CoreFoundation 0x000000019acf1fb8 409609CD-8410-38E1-BA5D-BDED609D2018 + 688056 46 CoreFoundation 0x000000019aceceac 409609CD-8410-38E1-BA5D-BDED609D2018 + 667308 47 CoreFoundation 0x000000019aced328 409609CD-8410-38E1-BA5D-BDED609D2018 + 668456 48 CoreFoundation 0x000000019acecc34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424 49 GraphicsServices 0x00000001a4e3638c GSEventRunModal + 160 50 UIKitCore 0x000000019ee1f22c UIApplicationMain + 1932 51 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001035fc2c8 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 18575920 52 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001035380b0 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 17772568 53 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000103538034 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 17772444 54 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000102526ed4 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 925244 55 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001028acc20 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 4619144 56 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001055382a8 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 51327504 57 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001055f3784 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 52094700 58 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001055f99dc GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 52119876 59 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000105516860 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 51189704 60 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001056d3664 xamarin_release_block_on_main_thread + 27000 61 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000102526a9c GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 924164 62 libdyld.dylib 0x000000019ab74800 876FB49A-BFBA-37BF-AD37-6FFC90F7F981 + 6144

```
Stack traces
Runtime.ThrowNSException (System.IntPtr ns_exception)
Runtime.throw_ns_exception (System.IntPtr exc)
(wrapper native-to-managed) ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception(intptr)
(wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.objc_msgSend(intptr,intptr,intptr)
UIView.AddSubview (UIKit.UIView view)
FrameRenderer.OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e)
VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element)
IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)
RendererPool.UpdateRenderers (Xamarin.Forms.Element newElement)
RendererPool.UpdateNewElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement)
VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement)
VisualElementPackager.OnRendererElementChanged (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementChangedEventArgs args)
VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e)
VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element)
IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)
RendererPool.UpdateRenderers (Xamarin.Forms.Element newElement)
RendererPool.UpdateNewElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement)
VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement)
VisualElementPackager.OnRendererElementChanged (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementChangedEventArgs args)
VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e)
VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element)
IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)
ViewCellRenderer+ViewTableCell.UpdateCell (Xamarin.Forms.ViewCell cell)
ViewCellRenderer+ViewTableCell.set_ViewCell (Xamarin.Forms.ViewCell value)
ViewCellRenderer.GetCell (Xamarin.Forms.Cell item, UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv)
XFGlossViewCellRenderer.GetCell (Xamarin.Forms.Cell item, UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv)
CellTableViewCell.GetNativeCell (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Xamarin.Forms.Cell cell, System.Boolean recycleCells, System.String templateId)
ListViewRenderer+ListViewDataSource.GetCell (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
(wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate)
UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName)
Application.Main (System.String[] args)
(wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.objc_msgSend(intptr,intptr,intptr)
UIView.AddSubview (UIKit.UIView view)
FrameRenderer.OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e)
VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element)
IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)
RendererPool.UpdateRenderers (Xamarin.Forms.Element newElement)
RendererPool.UpdateNewElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement)
VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement)
VisualElementPackager.OnRendererElementChanged (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementChangedEventArgs args)
VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e)
VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element)
IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)
RendererPool.UpdateRenderers (Xamarin.Forms.Element newElement)
RendererPool.UpdateNewElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement)
VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement)
VisualElementPackager.OnRendererElementChanged (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementChangedEventArgs args)
VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e)
VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element)
IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)
ViewCellRenderer+ViewTableCell.UpdateCell (Xamarin.Forms.ViewCell cell)
ViewCellRenderer+ViewTableCell.set_ViewCell (Xamarin.Forms.ViewCell value)
ViewCellRenderer.GetCell (Xamarin.Forms.Cell item, UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv)
XFGlossViewCellRenderer.GetCell (Xamarin.Forms.Cell item, UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv)
CellTableViewCell.GetNativeCell (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Xamarin.Forms.Cell cell, System.Boolean recycleCells, System.String templateId)
ListViewRenderer+ListViewDataSource.GetCell (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
(wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate)
UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName)
Application.Main (System.String[] args)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, it turns out i am not the only one
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11183
seems to be a bug in listview.
downgrade to Xamarin.Forms version 4.6.0.847 will solve this problem

Comment: You can mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: don't know i can ask. answer and mark all by myself :) thank you