# Xamarin Forms crash report in iOS App - GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, admob, exc-bad-access

I'm getting the below crash report from Crashlytics for our Xamarin.Forms iOS app.
I'm not sure whether this is due to Google Mobile Ads (Admob - we're using the latest version) after seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62737087/xamarin-forms-ios-app-starts-crashing-randomly) link.
I need some directions for debugging the cause of this issue. Thanks!

Xamarin.Forms Version = 5.0.0.1709-pre4

Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds Version = 7.66.0

```
Crashed: Thread Pool Worker
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE 0x000000016e70ffe0

Crashed: Thread Pool Worker
0  AppName.iOS                  0x103f91a38 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 30094532
1  AppName.iOS                  0x1025103d0 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 2301532
2  AppName.iOS                  0x102510154 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 2300896
3  AppName.iOS                  0x10266b2a4 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 3722544
4  AppName.iOS                  0x10266d134 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 3730368
5  AppName.iOS                  0x10335a17c GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 17284104
6  AppName.iOS                  0x103830148 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22354900
7  AppName.iOS                  0x103830250 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22355164
8  AppName.iOS                  0x103833884 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22369040
9  AppName.iOS                  0x10385b4a4 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
10 AppName.iOS                  0x10385b4f0 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
11 AppName.iOS                  0x10385b4a4 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
12 AppName.iOS                  0x10387dc80 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
13 AppName.iOS                  0x1025a258c GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
14 AppName.iOS                  0x102529fac GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
15 AppName.iOS                  0x102529dac GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
16 AppName.iOS                  0x1025a2448 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
17 AppName.iOS                  0x102547070 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
18 AppName.iOS                  0x102540b08 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
19 AppName.iOS                  0x10253f0c0 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
20 AppName.iOS                  0x10253a054 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
21 AppName.iOS                  0x1025a0cdc GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
22 AppName.iOS                  0x102ffdb14 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
23 AppName.iOS                  0x1025a258c GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
24 AppName.iOS                  0x102529fac GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
25 AppName.iOS                  0x102529dac GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
26 AppName.iOS                  0x1025a2448 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
27 AppName.iOS                  0x102547070 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
28 AppName.iOS                  0x102540b08 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
29 AppName.iOS                  0x10253f0c0 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
30 AppName.iOS                  0x10253a054 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
31 AppName.iOS                  0x1025a0cdc GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
32 AppName.iOS                  0x1030d3b1c GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
33 AppName.iOS                  0x1025a258c GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
34 AppName.iOS                  0x102529fac GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
35 AppName.iOS                  0x102529dac GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
36 AppName.iOS                  0x1025a2448 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
37 AppName.iOS                  0x102547070 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
38 AppName.iOS                  0x102540b08 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
39 AppName.iOS                  0x10253f0c0 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
40 AppName.iOS                  0x10253a054 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
41 AppName.iOS                  0x10253649c GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
42 AppName.iOS                  0x1030d0d30 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
43 AppName.iOS                  0x10276cc28 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
44 AppName.iOS                  0x10253f5f4 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
45 AppName.iOS                  0x10253f868 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
46 AppName.iOS                  0x102529fac GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
47 AppName.iOS                  0x102529dac GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
48 AppName.iOS                  0x102543718 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
49 AppName.iOS                  0x10253f780 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
50 AppName.iOS                  0x10253f658 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
51 AppName.iOS                  0x10252ef68 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
52 AppName.iOS                  0x1030d7620 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
53 AppName.iOS                  0x102531028 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
54 AppName.iOS                  0x1027b4760 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
55 AppName.iOS                  0x103e1c668 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
56 AppName.iOS                  0x103ed9648 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
57 AppName.iOS                  0x103f1cc94 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
58 AppName.iOS                  0x103f1a570 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
59 AppName.iOS                  0x103f25d08 GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531964
60 AppName.iOS                  0x103f25b8c GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 22531888
61 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1dbafcbfc _pthread_start + 22531964
62 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1dbb05758 thread_start + 22531888
```

Comment: Can provide full logs if required..

Comment: Please provide full log cause there is no useful information here .

Comment: Thanks @ColeX-MSFT! Since this is from Crashlytics, by full logs, I meant the logs from other threads.. Will that be useful ?